# C# usercontrol not updating with DispatcherTimer Tick Event

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am having issues having a UserControl update in the main page by using a DispatcherTimer to signal to get pull new data from some temperature sensors.

Sensors.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class Sensors : UserControl
{
    public Sensors()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Sensorlbl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SensorlblProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SensorlblProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Sensorlbl.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SensorlblProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SensorLbl", typeof(string), typeof(Sensors), null);
```

Sensors.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="SensorLbl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Sensorlbl, ElementName=userControl, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        tempTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        tempTimer.Tick += GetTemp;
        tempTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        tempTimer.Start();

        Sensor1.Sensorlbl = "test";
    }
    public void GetTemp(object sender, object e)
    {
        Sensor1.Sensorlbl = "Test Working";

        Debug.WriteLine(Sensor1.Sensorlbl);
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<local:Sensors x:Name="Sensor1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="107" Height="155" />
```

With the above example I am just using that to try to prove out updating the UserControl being used within MainPage. When I run the program I get an output of "Test Working" but the screen still only shows "test".

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the DependencyProperty definition: SensorLbl vs Sensorlbl.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time working with c# (or anything that isn't industrial robot based programming). What do you mean I didn't show the implementation of Sensor1.Sensorlbl? The code I posted above is what I was running when I did this test. Should there be other parameters MainPage.xaml?

Comment: Yes that was the issue. I now feel kind of dumb for not catching that. Thanks

Comment: Let me write this as answer so we get this off the unanswered questions list. Please ignore my first comment - I somehow missed the UserControl code. I have already deleted that comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registration for a DependencyProperty is case sensitive. It has to match precisely the name of the property. In your case you have a mismatch: SensorLbl vs Sensorlbl.

Comment: Thanks again for you help.